# How to use Jquery code for Quiz showing each q at a time using Razor Syntax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have no Problem with my model and controller, but i have a problem in jquery code using a razor syntax, the first question is showing well, but when i click the next button no other question is showing.

**Here is my view**

```
<div class="container question">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md color-change-btn set-res1">Time Remaining: @Model.Duration min</button>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2 style="text-transform:capitalize">@Model.TestTitle</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ForQuestionModal)
        {
            <form class="form-horizontal abc" role="form" id="login" method="post" action="result.php" style="text-transform:capitalize">
                <div id="question1" class="cont hide">
                    <p class="questions" id="qname1">@item.QuestionTitle</p>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="radio1_6" name="6">@item.OptionA
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id="radio1_6" name="6">@item.OptionB
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id="radio1_6" name="6">@item.OptionC
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id="radio1_6" name="6">@item.OptionD
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" style="display:none" value="5" id="radio1_6" name="6">
                    <button id="1" class="next btn btn-success" type="button">Next</button>                 
                </div>
            </form>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is My Script**

```
$('.cont').addClass('hide');
count = $('.questions').length;
$('#question' + 1).removeClass('hide');

$(document).on('click', '.next', function () {
    last = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    nex = last + 1;
    $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');
    $('#question' + nex).removeClass('hide');
});

$(document).on('click', '.previous', function () {
    last = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    pre = last - 1;
    $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');
    $('#question' + pre).removeClass('hide');
});
```

i have a Quiz in online examination project, the questions coming from database,also i need to display a result at the end of quiz, please help me because i don't really know about the query code.

Comment: there showing only one question but when i click next button, then the previous question is hidden, the 2nd question is not showing and also the next button is disappear

Comment: i need to show all questions coming from database one by one clicking on next button, but only first question is showing right now.

Comment: Is there any special reason for using `$('.cont').addClass('hide');` instead of `$('.cont').hide();`?

Comment: could you set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in building HTML like multiple ids of html elements and use of Razor syntax is minimal.

1.If you are posting each answer then i think there is no use of using `@foreach (var item in Model.ForQuestionModal)` for displaying every question. Instead make your view strongly type with Model `@model Model` not `List<Model>`

2.For showing multiple option you could have use `@foreach(var o in item.Answers)`.

3.After posting the answer of first question, get the next question from database and populate in same view.

I think to reach up there you need to make some base changes. Below is a very abstract way:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal abc" role="form" id="login" method="post" action="result.php" style="text-transform:capitalize">
    <div id="@Model.ForQuestionModal.QuestionId)" class="cont hide">
        <p>
            @Model.ForQuestionModal.QuestionTitle
        </p>
    @foreach(var ans in Model.ForQuestionModal.Answers){
                <input type="radio" value="@ans.AnswerId" id=("radio_"+@ans.AnswerId) name="rdoption">@ans.AnswerText <br/>
    }
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" style="display:none" value="5" id="radio1_6" name="6">
            <br>
            <button class="next btn btn-success" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I dnt know this would help you or not but may change some way of thinking and build better HTML

Comment: i am sorry.. it doesn't work for me.. please send me quiz sample if you have any.. or send me link to download code. @Arjun